# ValueError in Anaconda frame.py or my program?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently using a Pandas DataFrame to store multiple different values from a text file called test1.txt. When I try to execute the program, it gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3147, in _set_value
    series._values[loc] = value

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'test1'
```

Does the issue originate in the frame.py file or my own program and how do I solve this?

Comment: the error occurs is in the pandas package but your code is the cause to this. if you dont provide your code, we cant help you to solve your problem. btw the error states what the problem is. you try to convert a string "test1" to float

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for your response! I just needed to know if the error was my fault or something wrong with the package. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: it looks like you are converting "test1" to a float, which is not possible